# Why are the animated UI Labels in my code starting from within the view?

Tags: ios, animation, swift2

I'm a very new-to-code learner. I've been taking some online courses, and came across this project recently.

I basically copied the code as I saw it on the screen, as the project files weren't available to download.
The animation is supposed to bring the UILabels from outside the view and position them within the view.
What seems to happen however, is the labels are starting *within* the view screen and animate outward and beyond.

I've copied the project below. Any help is so very appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var helloWorld: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hiddenLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        helloWorld.center.y -= view.bounds.height

        secondLabel.center.y += view.bounds.height

        hiddenLabel.alpha = 0.0

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

//  Animate Hello World label
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {

            self.helloWorld.center.y += self.view.bounds.height


            }, completion: { finished in
                self.secondAnimation()
        })

//  Animate background color change

        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 1.5, options: [], animations: {

            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        }, completion:nil)

    }

//  Animate second Label

    func secondAnimation() {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in

            self.secondLabel.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height

        }, completion:nil)

    }


    func backgroundColor() {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, animations: {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 1.5, options: [], animations: {
            self.hiddenLabel.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion:nil)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check hello world.center.y value in viewWillAppear, before you subtract the view.bounds.height. If center.y value is large and positive, then the subtraction might be setting the center.y value to be inside of the view. If this is the case, then you would want to change the subtraction in viewWillAppear to addition and then the addition in the viewDidAppear animation to subtraction.